# How to Stored Multiple Select option Database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I need to store multiple select option data to the database.I try with that but it takes only one option. I given the code below.

*Templates*

```
<select name="qualification" multiple>
<option value="">Select</option>
<script type="text/javascript">
                var functional=new Array("Any Graduates","Any UnderGraduates","Any PostGraduates","BE/BTech/MCA","BE/BTech","MCA","Other");
                for(var i=0;i<functional.length;i++)
                    document.write("<option value=\""+functional[i]+"\">"+functional[i]+"</option>");
            </script>
</select>
```

*models.py*

```
class edu(models.Model):
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*views.py*

```
def jobpost(request):
     if request.method=='POST':
     qualification=request.POST.get('qualification')
     s=edu(qualification=qualification)
     s.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation, accept some answers to your previous questions, and read the [forms section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
qualification = request.POST.getlist('qualification')
```